# How do I fix bugs while executing matlab standalone applications?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am currently trying to create a Matlab application as a standalone application. In Matlab, the program runs fine via the GUI, however, as soon as I install the application on my desktop and run it, I get the following error messages output to the command window:

1. Error using dicom_getFileDetails (line 14)
   Unable to load file "RE.#_STR_IMG.REGISTRATION.dcm".
2. Error in dicominfo (line 55)
3. Error in Apply_Registration/ApplyRegistrationButtonPushed (line 64)
4. Error in appdesigner.internal.service.AppManagementService/tryCallback (line 333)
5. Error in matlab.apps.AppBase>@(source,event)tryCallback(appdesigner.internal.service.AppManagementService.instance(),app,callback,requiresEventData,event) (line 35)
6. Error using matlab.ui.control.internal.controller.ComponentController/executeUserCallback (line 335)
   Error while evaluating button PrivateButtonPushedFcn.

Code:
1+2)

```
    % Button pushed function: OpenRegistrationFileButton
      function OpenRegistrationFileButtonPushed(app, event)
        
        % Open registration file
        app.File_registrationFile = uigetfile;
      end
```

3. ```
    reginfo = dicominfo(app.File_registrationFile);
   ```

What is the problem when running as a standalone application?

The Matlab Runtime Compiler matches my Matlab version. Unfortunately, I lack the expertise to move forward here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start with the obvious and read the error message :) the error message says "can't load file", so 1) where is the file? and 2) where is the program executing? Those two things have to match... Add a print pwd statement to your program right before the load statement. Likely the program is not executing where you think it is.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, but I want to install the application on other computers and it always reads different files. Does the user then always have to move the files into the path of the application for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently only outputting the file name from `uigetfile` ([docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html)), so subsequent usage of that file assume it's in the same folder as the executing app. This is likely not the case, hence the error that the file can't be loaded (because it doesn't exist).

You just need to be more explicit, get the path too and refer to the full file path instead of just the name

```
[file,path] = uigetfile;
app.File_registrationFile = fullfile( path, file );
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didn't know about fullfile. That fixed it!